# Why rotatelogs from apache produce files smaller than specified max size?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, logging

I use the following [rotatelogs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/programs/rotatelogs.html) command from Apache :

```
/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/somelogfile 1GB
```

If I send 1GB of content to it (for testing), it produces the following files :

```
somelogfile.1706304578  285'867'200  10:29:38
somelogfile.1706304579  375'848'960  10:29:39
somelogfile.1706304580  437'027'357  10:29:40
```

The sum of the size of all files is indeed 1GB but why did it rotated 3 times ? I expected one single file of 1GB to be created.

Also: the size and then number of files it produces seems to be random (eg: I might end up with 4 files, sometimes 2...)

---

There is a *verbose* mode that will redirect some output `STDERR` :

```
rotatelogs -v
```

It should give info about why the logs got rotated. However I'm unsure how to retrieve what is sent to `STDERR`. I tried this command :

```
rotatelogs /var/log/somelogfile 1GB -v 2> /tmp/error.txt
```

But without success (rotatelogs will not start)

Comment: IIRC messages to STDERR by apache httpd helper programmes will be logged in the ErrorLog and  with a directive like `CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs /var/log/logfile 5M" common`  you can't use shell constructs like an output/error redirect because no shell is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is wrong :

```
/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/somelogfile 1GB
```

should be

```
/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/somelogfile 1G
```

Thanks for *HBruijn* for his comment about STDERR.

---

Here is how I found it out :

To enable verbose mode

```
LogFile "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -v /var/log/somelogfile ..."
```

Then inspect the journal file :

```
journalctl -u httpd.service --since "5min ago"
```

In my case I got this :

```
Rotation size interval:                 1
...
File rotation needed, reason: Maximum size reached 
File rotation needed, reason: Maximum size reached
File rotation needed, reason: Maximum size reached (hundred of times)
...
```

Theoretically, it should have created 1'073'741'824 files of 1 byte, but instead just created a 3-4 files of hundred of MB.